# ArcGIS Grouping Analysis Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, spatial-statistics

I am trying to run the [Grouping Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Grouping_Analysis/005p00000051000000/) tool from Esri's ArcGIS Spatial Statistics/Mapping Clusters toolbox.  I have run the tool successfully on the same input layer using a different spatial weights matrix, but when I try to run the tool with an IDW spatial weights matrix the tool fails.  I have not seen this type of error before.  See image...

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing the 4 features that cause problem ?

Comment: yes, removed the bad records and still receiving the same result.